# Receiver FCM notification click event

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, flutter-dependencies

How can I receive the notification click event on flutter?

I write this code on main.dart but the onMessage handling events doesn't work.

This code block doesn't work on background too.

When the app working on background onMessage function doesn't handling.

**main.dart**

```
    FirebaseMessaging _firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging();
void iOS_Permission() {
  _firebaseMessaging.requestNotificationPermissions(
      IosNotificationSettings(sound: true, badge: true, alert: true)
  );
  _firebaseMessaging.onIosSettingsRegistered
      .listen((IosNotificationSettings settings)
  {
    print("Settings registered: $settings");
  });
}
void firebaseCloudMessaging_Listeners(BuildContext context) {
  if (Platform.isIOS) iOS_Permission();

  _firebaseMessaging.getToken().then((token){
    print("Token : ${token}");
  });

  _firebaseMessaging.configure(
    onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
      print('on message $message');
    },
    onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
      print('on resume $message');
    },
    onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
      Navigator.pushNamed(context, "/");
      print('on launch $message');
    },
  );
}
void main() {
  print("uygulama Acildi");
  debugPaintSizeEnabled = false;
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    localizationsDelegates: [
    GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
    GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
  ],supportedLocales: [
    const Locale('tr', 'TR'),
  ],
    theme: ThemeData(fontFamily: 'Oswald'),
    initialRoute: '/',
    routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
     // '/': (context) => SanalPulHareketleri(),
      '/': (context) => SplashEkrani(),
      '/kayit_ol': (context) => KayitOl(),
    },
  ));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **onMessage** is triggered when you receive a notification and App in Foreground is running.

Please have a look at **onResume** and **onLaunch** callbacks.
More information you could find [on the library page](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/firebase_messaging)